# ASP.NET MVC ajax request not found error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get data from server by ajax.

Here's my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController")',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 'skip': '5' },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error: STATUS = " + textStatus + "ERROR = " + errorThrown);
     }
});
```

and my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData(string skip)
{
    return new JsonResult() {Data = "test"};
}
```

with this code I get `404 not found error`, 
when I remove the `HttpPost` attribute I get `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: url:MyController/GetData

Comment: Check in browser console, whether you are hitting proper URL or not? while doing `post` action

Comment: Why don't you use `WEB Api` for http calls?

Comment: just check your controller name...

Comment: Check the generated code inside your `$.ajax` call, just to check that the url is correct.

Comment: @AndreiV in console i get this error "GET http://localhost:11915/mycontroller/getdata 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: just check controller name..

Comment: just try writing my instead mycontroller...

Comment: i tried with different name TestController, with url: Test/GetData and url: TestControlle/GetData, same error. Now i am reading Web API as suggested by @Giannis Paraskevopoulos

Comment: What's the actual name of your controller? Is it `MyControllerController` or `MyController`? If it's `MyController`, then, as Exception suggested, you need to write `url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "My")'`.

Comment: its is MyControllerController.

Comment: I don't really think that that's the issue here, but please change the name. Did you change something in the default routes?

Answer (score 0):

Change your AJAX url so it resembles the format:

`url: "controller/action"`

So in your case,

`url: "MyController/GetData"`

You could also try formatting your data field differently. For instance:

`data: "&skip=" + "5",`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Javascript function to get all types of URL:

```
function rootUrl(url) {
    var _rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
    var x = url;
    if (url.indexOf(_rootUrl) != 0) {
        x = _rootUrl + "/" + url;
        x = x.replace(/\/\//g, "/").replace(/\/\//g, "/");
    }
    return x;
};
```

then Use URL in your AJAX request as::

```
url: rootUrl("MyController/GetData")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute [FromBody] and action selector will not look for query string parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData([FromBody]string skip)
{
    return new JsonResult() {Data = "test"};
}
```